# Centre text horizontal and vertical in element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to center some text vertically and horizontal in my #modal element:

```
#modal
{
background: gray;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 427px;
    height: 999px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4js3runn/

```html
<div id="modal">
    <span>CENTRE THIS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564

Comment: thanks but i need an answer in my case. I dont know css.

Comment: Change #modal class to  #modal
{
background: gray;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 427px;
    height: 999px;
     display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

Answer (score 1):

see the jsfiddle code :
http://jsfiddle.net/4js3runn/1/

```
#modal {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 gray;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 100vh;

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    background-color: #444;
    height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -56px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 112px;
}
<div id="modal">
    <div class="center">CENTRE THIS</div>
</div>
```